# how to validating the date in angular ionic5 using typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic5

i have try many solutions but not working to validating the current date with enter date by user
in functions parameters date passed from the user how to perform validation
how to validate the date

```
isToday(date) {
    const today = new Date()
    return date.getDate() === today.getDate() &&
        date.getMonth() === today.getMonth() &&
        date.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear();
};

isToday(2020-09-07)
```

above code is not working can any one help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2020-09-07 is not a Date object you need to call isToday with new Date('2020-09-07')

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isToday(date) {
    const today = new Date()
    return date.getDate() === today.getDate() &&
        date.getMonth() === today.getMonth() &&
        date.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear();
};

console.log(isToday(new Date("2020-09-10")))
```

1. The console.log is just there to know its result.
2. 2020-09-07 is not a date. You gotta do Date("2020-09-07")

Also since you also added typescript in as a tag then you should be using types:

```
function isToday(date : Date) {
    const today = new Date()
    return date.getDate() === today.getDate() &&
        date.getMonth() === today.getMonth() &&
        date.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear();
};

console.log(isToday(new Date("2020-09-10")))
```